# A question on limit of $L^1$ norm of a conjugate Dirichlet kernel

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Let $$L_n = \int_{-1}^1 \left|\frac{cos(x/2)-cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)}{2sin(x/2)}\right|dx$$

What are $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{L_{2k+1}}{\log(2k+1)}$$ and $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{L_{2k}}{\log(2k)}$$

$k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The inequality given by Wikipedia for the $L^1$ norm of the Dirichlet kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) is tight and gives your limits. Let me know if you need the details, computations are pretty long but straightforward, just based on the principle that we may explicitly locate the stationary points of the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127714/2987 I want something like this but for Conjugate Kernel. The inequality in Wikipedia seem to be wrong by a factor of 2? Is it supposed to be $\frac{4}{\pi}$. It would be great if there is a work out to arrive at a result for the limit. I hope its same as for Dirichlet kernel, but I am not sure wether I go via odd or even numbers to get a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let $I_n$ be given by the integral

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\cos(x/2)-\cos((n+1/2)x}{\sin(x/2)}\right|\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

We exploit the evenness of the integrand in $(1)$ along with the trigonometric identity $1-\cos(\phi)=2\sin^2(\phi/2)$ to write

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=4\int_0^\pi\frac{\left|\sin^2(x/4)-\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)\right|}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx \tag 2\end{align}$$

Applying the triangle inequality to $(2)$ reveals the bounds

$$I_n\le 4\log(2) +4\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx\tag 3$$

$$I_n\ge \left|4\log(2) -4\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx\right|\tag 4$$

Now, we analyze further the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx$.

Enforcing the substitution $(2n+1)x/4\to x$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx&= \int_0^{(2n+1)\pi/4} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\frac{2n+1}{4}\sin\left(\frac{2x}{2n+1}\right)}\,dx
\end{align}$$

For asymptotically large $n$, the integrand behaves like $x/2$ and we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2((2n+1)x/4)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx&\sim \int_0^{(2n+1)\pi/4} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x/2}\,dx \\\\
&=\log(n+1/2)+O(1) \tag 5
\end{align}$$

Putting together $(3)-(5)$, we see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{I_n}{\log(n)}=4$$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.