# Counterexample to inverse Hausdorff-Young on the torus

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

The inequality
\begin{equation*}
\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)} \le \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\end{equation*}
is well-known. Moreover, as far as I understand, it has no `inverse version' with exchanged indices (not even up to a multiplicative constant). A counterexample is the function $x\mapsto\sin(x)/x$ that does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but whose Fourier transform (with the proper choice of $2\pi$'s) is a characteristic function, and thus bounded by 1.

I was wondering if working on the torus $\mathbb{T}$ would help in order to have an inverse inequality. Namely, if it is true that
\begin{equation*}
\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T})} \le C \|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^{\infty}}.
\end{equation*}
The counterexample for $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ above works because of a lack of integrability at infinity, which is not an issue on $\mathbb{T}$. I still definitely suspect that the inequality I wrote is not true, but I failed at finding a counterexample.

Comment: Try $f_n(e^{it})=\sum_{k=-n}^ne^{ikt}.$ Then $\|\hat{f_n}\|_\infty=1$ but $\|f_n\|_1$ behaves like a constant times $\log n.$

Comment: Thank you. I cannot say that I immediately see how to compute the $L^1$-norm, but I will think about it.

Comment: See  [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550283/about-the-order-of-the-l1-norm-of-the-dirichlet-kernel)